# So after all, what is this thing about topos theory and non-binary truth?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, metamathematics

**Disclaimer.** The question below is necessarily vague. I understand neither the subject matter *topos theory* nor the object about which my question is (the construction of a fractional / non-binary / elastic notion of truth). Thanks in advance for your patience.

---

I've often heard whispers of vague statements like: "*topos theory* can be used to give  continuous, subtle, and perhaps a much more interesting notion of *truth* (not just **True** or **False**, **Right** or **Wrong**, **Correct** or **Incorrect**)". For lack of better terminology, let us refer to this mysterious phenomenon / concept as *fractional truth*.

> **Question.** What is a minimal construction which already displays this phenomenon?

I have essentially no knowledge of topos theory (but a decent handle on set theory, group theory, and topology, etc., and I'm naively assuming that this should be sufficient to understand the would-be construction, which I'm also assuming can be made so simple).

Comment: It looks like you are ready to bargain, so perhaps [the third stage](https://doi.org/10.1090/bull/1556) is where you will find some useful ideas.

Comment: @AndrejBauer This is really relevant to my question. Thanks!

Comment: I have a colleague, Ramez Maalouf, who sadly passed away recently, and who had started to write a book on his work on the categorification of logic with $n$ truth values. He lectured once on the topic. I don't think the work got published. Maybe he was looking for a publisher.

Comment: I note the "abstract nonsense" tag on this "question".

Comment: I remember someone writing introductory notes focused on the example of the logic of (I think) the Sierpinski topos. I quite liked it and that's probably the simplest example of this (even if it is much more artificial than the examples in Andrej's paper). But I cannot remember who it was nor find these notes... Is there someone who see what I am talking about ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what [tag:abstract-nonsense] has to do with this question. I also believe that [tag:soft-question] is not appropriate: it's not fit to a question on the ground of being vague.

Comment: I've removed the "abstract nonsense" tag (though it seems to be quite a popular tag here on MO, for questions having to do with category theory, topos theory. The struggle is real ...)

Comment: @SimonHenry: Did you mean [A guided tour in the topos of graphs](https://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/ToposGraphs.pdf)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer : Thanks ! That is not the one I had in mind, but that's definitely in the same spirit and seems quite appropriate to answer the question as well.

Comment: In some parts of the world it is legal to smoke marijuana, in others it is not. This is a non-classical truth value in $\operatorname{Sh}(S^2)$.

Comment: This is probably related, I wrote a way of constructing a hierarchy or partial order of truth underpinned by the idea of Ockham's razor: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374624/

Comment: If you want to see a couple of examples for the wondrous non-classical facts holding in specific toposes, you can have a look at [these notes of mine](http://ingo-blechschmidt.eu/.exploring.pdf), particularly Section 2 and Section 3. I am happy to any questions you might have concerning these notes!

Comment: Thanks; will check it out. I was led directly (probably by an evil spirit) to the end of p6, in which something rather strange is happening: you define the sign function on $R$ and argue that in certain topoi, that function would defy the classical falsehood of "All functions $R \to R$ are continuous". At this point, completely disoriented, I'm wondering to my self, *Will this tower of abstractions give me anything which cannot be done via classical means, or is it conceptual freedom for the sake of conceptual freedom ? (which is fine, btw)*. A concrete example would be very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: To clarify: The sign function only seems to defy the cited classical falsehood. It doesn't really, as it cannot be shown to actually be a function $R \to R$. Regarding your greater question: I tried to give a short answer in Section 4.5. Briefly: both.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose you always want to talk about two things simultaneously for some reason. When you say "a set $A$" you actually mean a pair of sets $(A_1, A_2)$, when you say "a function $f : A \to B$" you mean a pair of functions $f_1 : A_1 \to B_1$, $f_2 : A_2 \to B_2$. When you say a statement $p$ is true, you actually mean $p_1$ is true and $p_2$ is true. Then from an external perspective there obviously are truth values which "are neither true nor false", namely $(true, false)$ and $(false, true)$. (Note that the partial order of truth values is not a total order here, so it is not very similar to fractional numbers.)

This is the internal language of the topos $\mathrm{Sh}(\{*\} \sqcup \{*\})$, the sheaf topos on the discrete two-point space. (A sheaf on this space is just a pair of sets.) If you take $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ instead, for $X$ any topological space, there are as many internal truth values as $X$ has open subsets.

Be careful, however, to distinguish between internal and external statements. The truth values $p = (\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false})$ and $(\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{true})$ are different externally, but the internal statement "$p$ is different from $\mathrm{true}$" has truth value $(\mathrm{false}, \mathrm{true})$, so it is not valid (everywhere). In fact, we can prove in intuitionistic logic (which is valid in every topos) that there is no truth value which is neither true nor false.

Also note that $\mathrm{Sh}(\{*\} \sqcup \{*\})$ is a boolean topos, that is, the internal language is in fact classical -- the law of omniscience (excluded middle) *is* valid internally. For example, $p \lor (\lnot p) = (\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false}) \lor (\mathrm{false}, \mathrm{true}) = (\mathrm{true} \lor \mathrm{false}, \mathrm{false} \lor \mathrm{true}) = (\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{true})$.

Comment: Thanks for the input (upvoted). i'm not sure I follow (first paragraph). What do you mean by "are neither true nor false" when you've only defined what it means for a statement to be "true" ? In this system, what does it mean to say something is "false" ? (This is classically defined to mean "not true", via excluded middle principle / axiom, I guess. But how to go about that here ?).

Comment: @dohmatob: it is quite impossible for anyone to define precisely all the details of the logic in a topos in an answer on MO, so you should give a great deal of leeway to the answer. It is just trying to illustrate a point, it's not a precise definition.

Comment: But to answer your question: in this topos we *always* use  pair of truth values. As far as the topos is concerned, "truth" is $(\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{true})$ and "falsehood" is $(\mathrm{false}, \mathrm{false})$. If you ask "Is $(\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false})$ equal to $\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{true})$?" the answer is "$(\mathrm{true}, \mathrm{false})$". Given any truth value $(p_1, p_2)$, the value of $\neg (p_1, p_2) \land \neg\neg (p_1, p_2)$ (whose meaning is "$(p_1, p_2)$ is neither true nor false") is $(\mathrm{false}, \mathrm{false})$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks for the clarification.